# Recursion with Pointers in C

Tags: c, function, pointers, recursion

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int x=2,y=4,z=17,w=3,count=0;

    void p(int z,int *x){
        *x= 3*z - *x;
        int  w=*x+z;
        printf("%d %d %d %d \n",*x,y,z,w);
        if(*x<=y){
           p(*x+1,&w);         
           printf("%d %d %d %d \n",*x,y,z,w);
        }
     }                          


   int main(void){

       p(1,&x);
       printf("%d %d %d %d \n",x,y,z,w);
       return 0;
    }
```

I try to run this code by hand in order to take the output but the results that i produce by hand are different from the output which i have when i compile and execute it.
Can anyone explain to me in detail how the output of the program is created ?

The output that is supposed to give is

```
1 4 1 2 
4 4 2 6 
9 4 5 14 
4 4 2 9 
1 4 1 4 
1 4 17 3
```

Comment: What results do you get by hand?

Comment: This a really poorly written recursion, very hard to follow.  Does it have a purpose other than confuse people?

Comment: i get      1 4 1 2   \  4 4 2 6 \ 9 4 5 14  by hand .          After that i don't know how to continue .This was an exercises in a exam.

Comment: You could just use your debugger to see what your code is doing...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process this by hand, you should draw a stack in a paper and push values of x, y, z, w before every recursive call, & pop them in the end. Since we have one recursive call in the procedure, i think that would be easy to do.